# C# Progress Bar , Thread , Foreachs anidados

Tags: c#, hilos

Buenas...

Tengo la siguiente situación:

Tengo dos listas , la primera de aproximadamente 9000 objetos, y la segunda de 44000 (ésto puede variar de una ejecución a la siguiente).

Ahora bien, tengo que encontrar cada item de la lista A en la lista B, setear un par de atributos y luego seguir trabajando con los de la lista A modificados.

Para ésto, tengo dos foreach anidados en un nuevo Thread y pretendo ir llenando una ProgressBar mientras dura el proceso (ésto de los Threads es nuevo para mi en C#)

El problema es que mientras se está realizando el proceso, obtengo una excepción del tipo:

> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException

Aquí el código:

```
private void btn_readTXT_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog file = new OpenFileDialog();

        if (file.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            Thread backgroundThread = new Thread( 
            new ThreadStart(() =>
            {
                string url = file.FileName;
                IBs = otequiste.ReadFile(url); //Lleno la lista desde el txt

                foreach (cliente cliente in Clientes)
                {
                    foreach (tequiste ib in IBs)
                    {
                        if (cliente.Cli_CUIT == ib.Cuit) 
                        {
                            cliente.Actividad = ib.Cod_act;
                            cliente.Riesgo = ib.Riesgo;
                            cliente.Tipo = ib.Tipo;

                            progressBar1.BeginInvoke(
                            new Action(() =>
                            {
                                progressBar1.Value += 1;
                            }
                        ));
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }

                MessageBox.Show("Ready", "Ready ? ");


            }));
            backgroundThread.Start();
        }           
    }
```

Mis dudas son las siguientes:

a) ¿Que significa ésta excepción? (No se bien cuando ocurre, la barra se llena hasta la mita despues de unos 5 seg aprox, me deja el editor del visual en el archivo Program.cs en una línea que dice:

```
Application.Run(new Form1());
```

b) Teniendo en cuenta que la cantidad de objetos en las listas varía de una ejecución a la siguiente ¿Como puedo realizar efectivamente el llenado de la progress bar?

(o sea, calcular el 100% y saber cuanto ir aumentando el Value para que no se salga de rango o se quede corta)

Comment: `Total=Clientes.Length*IBs.Length` con eso te daria el total de iteracion el problema es el break en tu for anidado, lo que podrías hacer es usar un segundo contador en tu primer for y `CounterAjuste++;` `counter=CounterAjuste*IBs.Length`, para ir ajustando el avance tras un break.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dada la plática que tuvimos en el [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/38141286#38141286), se identificaron dos problemas, uno era el *performance* ya que al tener un `foreach` anidado prácticamente estás haciendo un producto cruzado, y el segundo era el valor del `progressBar1`, se salía del rango permitido.

La solución a la sección del *performance* consiste en buscar el valor `cliente.Cli_CUIT` por medio de Linq:

```
foreach (cliente cliente in Clientes)
{
    var ib = (from p in IBs
            where p.Cuit == cliente.Cli_CUIT
            select p).FirstOrDefault();

    if(ib != null) {
        cliente.Actividad = ib.Cod_act;
        cliente.Riesgo = ib.Riesgo;
        cliente.Tipo = ib.Tipo;

        progressBar1.BeginInvoke(
        new Action(() =>
        {
            //progressBar1.Value += 1;
        }
    }
}
```

La línea `progressBar1.Value += 1;` la dejo comentada, esto debido a que el código ha cambiado con las modificaciones que realizaste y con las que ya se encuentra trabajando de forma correcta. El problema consistía en que el valor máximo permitido para un `ProgressBar` es 100, entonces al incrementarlo en 1 con cada iteración llegaba un momento que se salía de ese rango, la solución consitió en dividir la cantidad de registros  procesados al momento de cada iteración de clientes entre el número total clientes.